# Как можно скомпилировать C++ Linux/Android/etc программу из-под Windows?

Tags: c++, компиляция, кроссплатформенность

Вопрос в заголовке. Как можно скомпилировать бинарник для использования на Linux/Android/etc, используя Windows? Для сборки использую make, но, вроде, gcc не умеет собирать те же Linux'овые бинарники из-под винды.

Аналогичный вопрос для статичных и динамических библиотек. Как я понял, тот же NDK может компилировать .so файлы из-под Windows, однако, я так и не разобрался как.

UPD1: Под сборкой из-под Windows я имел ввиду именно сборку из-под Windows. Виртуальные машины - хороший вариант, но мне не подходит.

UPD2: Хорошими вариантами можно назвать следующие:

1. Установка CoLinux и компиляция с его помощью https://stackoverflow.com/a/21550741/10400333

2. Использование crosstool-ng для создания компилера для кросс-компиляции:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770417/10400333

Comment: Под линукс немного сложно, насколько я знаю. Проще поставить виртуальную машину и компилировать там.

Comment: То, что вы ищите, называется кросс-компиляция (cross-compilation).

Comment: На счет андроида: Если вы хотите под него компилировать, то должно быть уже подобрали графическую библиотеку? Если да, какую? В мануалах к SDL2, например, если подробная инструкция по сборке под андроид.

Comment: На windows 10, есть bash, на нем можно компилировать

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Я собираюсь использовать нативный OpenGL3.0 в моём движке. Это самый оптимальный вариант, ибо делать прослойку в виде солянки любой современной высокоуровневой библиотеки ради не сильно замысловатой 2Д-графики - немного отстой.

Comment: "*Под сборкой из-под Windows я имел ввиду именно сборку из-под Windows. Виртуальные машины - хороший вариант, но мне не подходит*" - ну компиляция ладно, а отладку вы как собираетесь производить без VM? Или речь идет не о разработке, а нужно просто перекомпилировать готовую рабочую программу?

Comment: @dreemlees OpenGL сам по себе не умеет открывать окно. Вам нужна для этого еще какая-то библиотека (например SDL2). Еще, на андроиде, ЕМНИП, есть только OpenGL ES (2.0 или 3.x).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Подразумевался именно GLES, а окно открывать - через ESL.

Comment: @freim Десктоп отладка производится на Windows и нужно просто перекомпилировать. А мобильная - на реальном устройстве. Конечно, на винде можно делать апкшники через NDK и Ant, но я хочу собирать и подписывать сам, не подключая лишние грэйдлы и прочие не самые полезные вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«[Это возможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769968/c-cross-compiler-from-windows-to-linux), но очень, *очень* дорого» © анекдот.

Действительно, как указали в комментариях, может получиться проще поставить виртуальную машину с тем же дебианом или убунту гигабайт на сорок, сделать там `apt-get install build-essential` и получить минимальный набор для компиляции C/C++, родные инструменты для сборки пакетов в .deb и т.д.

Учтите ещё, что понятие «бинарник для Linux» весьма расплывчато само по себе, т.к. линуксы все разные даже на одной и той же аппаратной платформе: в разных дистрибутивах разные версии динамических библиотек. Ну и, конечно, разные платформы.

Answer (score 1):

Могу сказать за обратный процесс. Из под линукса компилирование виндовых программ возможно. Только нужно скачивать виндовый компилятор mingw, который работает под линукс. Скорее всего в винде это также возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2017 позволяет разрабатывать программы для Linux. Но компиляция и отладка там происходит в Linux. Делается это так:

Запускается виртуальная машина с Линуксом (я делал это с VMware), там должен быть установлен компилятор и отладчик (все это подробно описано в хелпе VS). В сетевых настройках VM указывается IP, на котором эта VM должна сидеть (локальный адрес из 192.168.x.x годится).

В VS создается Линукс проект (при установке VS эта возможность должна быть включена), и в настройках указывается IP виртуальной машины. Это все, дальше разработка и отладка делается так же, как и для Windows.

VS 2017 поддерживает разработку и для мобильных платформ (на С++ для Андроид, к примеру), но сам не пробовал, так что ничего тут не могу сказать.